# Reflections in locally presentable categories-unclear step in the proof

Tags: category-theory, representable-functor, locally-presentable-categories

[Here](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/107343/ArchMath_025-1989-1_12.pdf) in the paper by Rosicky Adamek, Reflections in locally presentable categories on the page 90 in the proof theorem on the page 89, I do not follow
the 3rd line there:

**... and hence is reflective in $\cal H'\ ?$**

From which line in the last paragraph on the page 89 and from that 3rd line
on the page 90

(...thus is reflective in $\mathbf{Set}^M)$

this follows 
and why technically do we need this
?

I've read those two paragraphs on pages 89 and 90 many times but I've failed to understand them well enough.

**The snippet**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us reformulate the statement of the theorem, to introduce a name for the subcategory that we will want to consider.

> Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a locally presentable category and let $\alpha$ be a regular cardinal. Then each full subcategory $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal{H}$, that is closed under limits and $\alpha$-filtered colimits, is reflective in $\mathcal{H}$.

As they already mention, every locally presentable category $\mathcal{H}$ is equivalent to a full reflective subcategory $\mathcal{H'}$ of some presheaf category $\mathbf{Set}^M$, where $\mathcal{H'}$ is closed under $\beta$-filtered colimits in $\mathbf{Set}^M$. That is, we have the following picture:
$$
\mathcal{A} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{H} \simeq \mathcal{H'} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{Set}^M.
$$
In particular, the composed inclusion $\mathcal{A} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{Set}^M$ makes it so that we can see $\mathcal{A}$ as a full subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}^M$ that is closed under $(\alpha + \beta)$-filtered colimits. Then they claim that proving that this inclusion makes $\mathcal{A}$ into a reflective subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}^M$ is enough.

Indeed it is, denote by $i: \mathcal{A} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{H}$ and $j: \mathcal{H} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{Set}^M$ the inclusions. Then the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ is reflective in $\mathbf{Set}^M$ means that we have an adjoint $F \dashv ji$. So we have natural bijections between the hom-sets as follows (for objects $A$ in $\mathcal{A}$ and $H$ in $\mathcal{H}$):
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{A}(Fj(H), A) \cong
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}^M}(j(H), ji(A)) \cong
\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{H}(H, i(A))
$$
The first bijection is just the adjunction $F \dashv ji$, and the second bijection is just the fact that the inclusion $j$ is full and faithful. We thus see that $Fj \dashv i$, and so we can conclude that $\mathcal{A}$ is a reflective subcategory of $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: You explanationm has helped. I do not however understand some points yet. Why $j$ from $\cal H$ is an **inclusion** into $\mathbf{Set}^M$: $$j: \mathcal{H} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{Set}^M$$  when we have only $\cal H\cong H'$ which equivalence might not be an inclusion.

Comment: Also I do not follow why this natural bijection exists $$
\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{A}(Fj(H), A) \cong
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}^M}(j(H), ji(A))$$

Comment: @user3357120 You are right that an equivalence might not be an inclusion. So if we are being very precise, we could take $\mathcal{A'}$ to be the full subcategory of $\mathcal{H'}$ where the objects are the image of $\mathcal{A} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{H} \simeq \mathcal{H'}$. Note that by construction then $\mathcal{A'} \simeq \mathcal{A}$. We can repeat what I wrote with $\mathcal{A'}$ and $\mathcal{H'}$ in the role of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ respectively...

Comment: ...  Then we can conclude that $\mathcal{A'}$ is a reflective subcategory of $\mathcal{H'}$, and thus that $\mathcal{A}$ is a reflective subcategory of $\mathcal{H}$ because they are equivalent categories. This is essentially just saying that equivalent categories can considered to be equal. Taking that viewpoint often simplifies things, and is what I did in my answer.

Comment: @user3357120 For your second question: this is just the adjunction $F \dashv ji$. I will edit my answer to explain the two bijections.

Comment: How do you know that $j$ is **full and faithfull** ? How do you derive from it that $$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}^M}(j(H), ji(A)) \cong
\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{H}(H, i(A))$$ ?

Comment: @user3357120 If you just use the argument with $\mathcal{A'}$ and $\mathcal{H'}$ as I described in my comment, then $j$ is simply the inclusion of $\mathcal{H'}$ into $\mathbf{Set}^M$ and is therefore full and faithful by definition. But also the composition $\mathcal{H} \simeq \mathcal{H'} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{Set}^M$ is full and faithful. This is because it is a composition of full and faithful functors: one is an inclusion of a full subcategory and the other is an equivalence, which is always full and faithful (small exercise to prove this).

Comment: @user3357120 Also, the bijection $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}^M}(j(H), ji(A)) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{H}(H, i(A))$ is the definition of full and faithful applied directly to the objects $H$ and $i(A)$.